# is there any App in iOS we can get the List of URL being hit by some other app?

Tags: ios, url, ipa, sniffing

i was wondering is there any app in iOS which can get the list of URL being hit by other app installed on the same device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unless you're jailbroken or can route your device's traffic through a proxy.